# How can I get my Steam Game to Launch?

Tags: steam, sonic-cd

I just bought Sonic CD on my Steam account. Whenever I try to play it, A window opens up giving me two options: "Play Sonic CD", or "Video Setup."

If I choose "Play Sonic CD", Steam will go to a loading screen for a second or two and then just bring me back to the Steam Menu. If I choose "Video Setup", a different window comes up allowing me to change the window size for the game.

I don't know what I need to do to get the game to launch. If you know how this problem can be fixed, please tell me how I can fix it?

Comment: Is any error message presented when the game exits? Have you tried running Steam as an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

The usual steps i would take in the same situation is,

1. Find the launch .exe for the game in its directory and make sure you run it as Admin.
2. Select the video settings option and make sure that it is suitable for your PC
3. Depending on which version of windows you are using, possibly run it in compatability     mode for a previous version like windows 7 if you are on windows 8

- Last resort: Reinstall the game.

Comment: Due to the age of the game itself compatability mode would be required on anything later then Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a directx issue

> Steam\steamapps\common\sonic cd\directx

Run the file DXSETUP and it will updates your directx setup with necessary files